# Unable to post jdbc kafka sink connector config using rest call

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I created the distributed connect cluster using following file:

```
    rest.host.name=localhost
    rest.port=8083
    rest.advertised.host.name=localhost
    rest.advertised.port=8083
    bootstrap.servers=kafka:9093
    group.id=abc-connect-cluster-st
    key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    key.converter.schema.registry.url=https://sr:8081
    value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    value.converter.schema.registry.url=https://sr:8081
    key.converter.schemas.enable=true
    value.converter.schemas.enable=true
    offset.storage.topic=abc-offset
    config.storage.topic=abc-config
    status.storage.topic=abc-storage
    plugin.path=share/java
    sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
    security.protocol=SASL_SSL
    ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password=changeit
    ssl.keystore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.keystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.password=changeit
    ssl.key.password=changeit
    sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
    username="user" \
    password="password";
    consumer.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks
    consumer.ssl.truststore.password=changeit
    consumer.ssl.keystore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.keystore.jks
    consumer.ssl.keystore.password=changeit
    consumer.ssl.key.password=changeit
    consumer.sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
    consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
    consumer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
    username="user" \
    password="password";
    schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks
    schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password=changeit
    schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.keystore.jks
    schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password=changeit
    schema.registry.ssl.key.password=changeit
    schema.registry.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
    username="user" \
    password="password";
    schema.registry.sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
    schema.registry.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
```

when it run it using : `connect-distributed ./etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties`  i get following logs:

```
    [2020-03-19 19:07:02,990] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=abc-connect-cluster-st] Joined group at generation 19 with protocol version 2 and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-daa61c76-fbb0-4696-89c5-8a63695b3c34', leaderUrl='http://localhost:8083/', offset=-1, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[], revokedConnectorIds=[], revokedTaskIds=[], delay=0} with rebalance delay: 0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1540)
    [2020-03-19 19:07:02,990] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=abc-connect-cluster-st] Starting connectors and tasks using config offset -1 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1104)
    [2020-03-19 19:07:02,990] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=abc-connect-cluster-st] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1125)
```

which indicates my connect cluster is working at http://localhost:8083/

Next I post my mysql sink connector config:

```
{
    "name": "abc-sink-connect-st",
    "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "topic",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc_db",
    "connection.user": "root",
    "connection.password": "password",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://sr:8081",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://sr:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location": "/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password": "changeit",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location": "/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.keystore.jks",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password": "changeit",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location": "/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password": "changeit",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location": "/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.keystore.jks",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password": "changeit",
    "insert.mode": "insert"
    }
}
```

I get a 201 HTTP response with output:

```
{
    "name": "abc-sink-connect-st",
    "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "topic",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc_db",
    "connection.user": "root",
    "connection.password": "password",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://sr:8081",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://sr:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location": "/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password": "changeit",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location": "/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.keystore.jks",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password": "changeit",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location": "/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password": "changeit",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location": "/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.keystore.jks",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password": "changeit",
    "insert.mode": "insert"
    },
    "tasks": [],
    "type": "sink"
}
```

but nothing in the logs other than:

```
[2020-03-19 19:09:14,268] INFO AbstractConfig values:
(org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:347)

http://localhost:8083/connectors/ says []
No connectors were configured.
```

Can anybody please help me understand why am I not able to post the jdbc sink connector configuration when the exactly same setup works for standalone connect along with sink.properties file.

Thanks in advance.

I updated log level from INFO to DEBUG and when I post my json i still get the response 201 but i found following exceptions in the logs:

```
DEBUG SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=30004/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} idle timeout check, elapsed: 30004 ms, remaining: -4 ms (org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout:161)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,432] DEBUG SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=30004/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} idle timeout expired (org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout:168)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,433] DEBUG onFail FillInterest@2fa1a47e{AC.ReadCB@428dc26b{HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=30005/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}}} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest:134)
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30004/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,435] DEBUG close HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1} (org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser:1804)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,435] DEBUG START --> CLOSE (org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser:1832)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,435] DEBUG HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=30007/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} onFillInterestedFailed {} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection:167)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,436] DEBUG shutdownOutput SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=30007/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint:120)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,436] DEBUG fillInterested HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=30008/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection:133)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,436] DEBUG interested FillInterest@2fa1a47e{AC.ReadCB@428dc26b{HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}}} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest:79)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,436] DEBUG Selector sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@3ed14ffe woken up from select, 1/1/1 selected (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:479)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,436] DEBUG changeInterests p=false 1->1 for SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint:418)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,437] DEBUG Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1@52be2f8a on ManagedSelector@58f50dd0{STARTED} id=1 keys=1 selected=1 updates=0 (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:162)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,436] DEBUG Selector sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@3ed14ffe processing 1 keys, 0 updates (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:492)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,437] DEBUG ignored: WriteFlusher@3a9f0554{IDLE}->null (org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher:490)
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30004/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,437] DEBUG selected 1 channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected oshut local=/127.0.0.1:8083 remote=/127.0.0.1:56089], selector=sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@3ed14ffe, interestOps=1, readyOps=1 SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}  (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:521)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,471] DEBUG Ignored idle endpoint SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=FI,flush=-,to=34/30000}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint:420)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,471] DEBUG onSelected 1->0 r=true w=false for SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=FI,flush=-,to=34/30000}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint:344)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,471] DEBUG task CEP:SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}:runFillable:BLOCKING (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint:356)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,472] DEBUG ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=1/12,p=0} tryExecute EatWhatYouKill@5daad59a/SelectorProducer@5256fbc/PRODUCING/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[qtp292536990]@116fc29e{STARTED,8<=9<=200,i=1,r=12,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=1/12,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=1,epc=1]@2020-04-08T11:45:24.472168+02:00 (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor:191)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,472] DEBUG ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=0/12,p=0}@11045320 offer EatWhatYouKill@5daad59a/SelectorProducer@5256fbc/PRODUCING/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[qtp292536990]@116fc29e{STARTED,8<=9<=200,i=1,r=12,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=0/12,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=1,epc=1]@2020-04-08T11:45:24.472492+02:00 (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor:260)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,472] DEBUG ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=0/12,p=1} startReservedThread p=1 (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor:227)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,472] DEBUG queue ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=0/12,p=1}@7e0c212c startThread=false (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool:521)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,472] DEBUG run ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=0/12,p=1}@7e0c212c in QueuedThreadPool[qtp292536990]@116fc29e{STARTED,8<=9<=200,i=0,r=12,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=0/12,p=1}] (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool:917)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,473] DEBUG ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=1/12,p=1}@7e0c212c started (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor:348)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,473] DEBUG EatWhatYouKill@5daad59a/SelectorProducer@5256fbc/IDLE/p=true/QueuedThreadPool[qtp292536990]@116fc29e{STARTED,8<=9<=200,i=0,r=12,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=0/12,p=1}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=1,epc=1]@2020-04-08T11:45:24.473095+02:00 m=EXECUTE_PRODUCE_CONSUME t=CEP:SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=FI,flush=-,to=1/30000}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}:runFillable:BLOCKING/BLOCKING (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill:291)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,473] DEBUG ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=0/12,p=1}@11045320 task=EatWhatYouKill@5daad59a/SelectorProducer@5256fbc/IDLE/p=true/QueuedThreadPool[qtp292536990]@116fc29e{STARTED,8<=9<=200,i=0,r=12,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=1/12,p=1}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=1,epc=1]@2020-04-08T11:45:24.473274+02:00 (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor:318)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,473] DEBUG ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=1/12,p=0}@7e0c212c waiting (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor:277)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,473] DEBUG EatWhatYouKill@5daad59a/SelectorProducer@5256fbc/IDLE/p=true/QueuedThreadPool[qtp292536990]@116fc29e{STARTED,8<=9<=200,i=0,r=12,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=1/12,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=1,epc=2]@2020-04-08T11:45:24.473717+02:00 tryProduce true (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill:141)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,473] DEBUG updateable 1 (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:418)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,473] DEBUG fillable FillInterest@2fa1a47e{AC.ReadCB@428dc26b{HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=FI,flush=-,to=1/30000}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}}} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest:99)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,474] DEBUG update org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1@52be2f8a (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:427)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,474] DEBUG HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=2/30000}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} onFillable enter HttpChannelState@8db6297{s=IDLE a=NOT_ASYNC i=true r=IDLE w=false} null (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection:243)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,474] DEBUG Key interests updated 1 -> 0 on SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=2/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint:384)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,474] DEBUG updates 0 (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:447)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,474] DEBUG shutdownInput SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=3/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint:66)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,475] DEBUG Key interests updated 0 -> 0 on SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,OSHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=3/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint:384)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,475] DEBUG doClose SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=3/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint:194)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,475] DEBUG Selector sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@3ed14ffe waiting with 1 keys (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:465)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,475] DEBUG ignored: WriteFlusher@3a9f0554{IDLE}->null (org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher:490)
    java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.onClose(WriteFlusher.java:521)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.onClose(AbstractEndPoint.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.onClose(ChannelEndPoint.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.doOnClose(AbstractEndPoint.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.shutdownInput(AbstractEndPoint.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.fill(ChannelEndPoint.java:237)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:341)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:367)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:782)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:918)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,476] DEBUG onClose FillInterest@2fa1a47e{null} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest:147)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,476] DEBUG Wakeup ManagedSelector@58f50dd0{STARTED} id=1 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0 (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:188)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,476] DEBUG Selector sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@3ed14ffe woken with none selected (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:470)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,476] DEBUG queue org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DestroyEndPoint@7be31a92 startThread=true (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool:521)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,476] DEBUG Selector sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@3ed14ffe woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:479)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,476] DEBUG Starting Thread[qtp292536990-301,5,main] (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool:638)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,476] DEBUG Selector sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@3ed14ffe processing 0 keys, 0 updates (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:492)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,477] DEBUG filled -1 HeapByteBuffer@75be409[p=0,l=0,c=8192,r=0]={<<<>>>HTTP/1.1 201 Crea...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint:250)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,477] DEBUG Runner started for QueuedThreadPool[qtp292536990]@116fc29e{STARTED,8<=10<=200,i=0,r=12,q=1}[ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=1/12,p=0}] (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool:858)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,477] DEBUG updateable 0 (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:418)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,477] DEBUG run org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DestroyEndPoint@7be31a92 in QueuedThreadPool[qtp292536990]@116fc29e{STARTED,8<=10<=200,i=0,r=12,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=1/12,p=0}] (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool:917)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,477] DEBUG atEOF HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1} (org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser:1794)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,477] DEBUG updates 0 (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:447)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,477] DEBUG Destroyed SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=6/30000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:954)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,477] DEBUG HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=6/30000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} filled -1 HeapByteBuffer@75be409[p=0,l=0,c=8192,r=0]={<<<>>>HTTP/1.1 201 Crea...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection:350)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,478] DEBUG onClose HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=6/30000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection:225)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,478] DEBUG close SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=6/30000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint:174)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,477] DEBUG Selector sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@3ed14ffe waiting with 0 keys (org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector:465)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,478] DEBUG close(null) SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=6/30000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint:181)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,478] DEBUG ran org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DestroyEndPoint@7be31a92 in QueuedThreadPool[qtp292536990]@116fc29e{STARTED,8<=10<=200,i=0,r=12,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@1fb71788{s=1/12,p=0}] (org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool:920)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,478] DEBUG HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=7/30000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} parse HeapByteBuffer@75be409[p=0,l=0,c=8192,r=0]={<<<>>>HTTP/1.1 201 Crea...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} {} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection:367)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,479] DEBUG parseNext s=CLOSE HeapByteBuffer@75be409[p=0,l=0,c=8192,r=0]={<<<>>>HTTP/1.1 201 Crea...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} (org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser:1450)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,479] DEBUG CLOSE --> CLOSED (org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser:1832)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,479] DEBUG HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=7/30000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} parsed false HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection:372)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,479] DEBUG releaseRequestBuffer HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=7/30000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection:220)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,479] DEBUG shutdownOutput SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=8/30000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} (org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint:120)
    [2020-04-08 11:45:24,479] DEBUG HttpConnection@428dc26b::SocketChannelEndPoint@4ce7f469{/127.0.0.1:56089<->/127.0.0.1:8083,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=8/30000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->HttpConnection@428dc26b[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@68ce7c2a{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@b64c223{r=2,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} onFillable exit HttpChannelState@8db6297{s=IDLE a=NOT_ASYNC i=true r=IDLE w=false} null (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection:301)
```

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, it was a typo updated it..Like I mention the same config works with standalone mode along with sink connector properties but does not in distributed mode when I try to do a curl with sink connector json payload

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, thanks for pointing it out. I updated log level from INFO to DEBUG and when I post my json i still get the response 201 but i found following exceptions in the logs. I posted them

Comment: TimeoutException and ClosedChannel indication some type of error... Not sure what those are, though... Have you tried running Connect in Docker?

Comment: Yes I was having the similar issues but it was a while ago and then I switch to using normal properties file for easier debug. If you think using docker could help I can try with docker as well

Comment: It would be more reproducible on other's machines.

Comment: tried with docker too still the same problem

Comment: Which image did you try? Can you update the question?

Comment: guys, ran into same issue, I am using confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.0 docker image and I am on multi cloud with VPN connectivity in between..